Do I have to scald home made soy milk when making yoghurt with a machine
I have been successfully making yoghurt using store-bought soy milk from long-life cartons. Now I have purchased a soy milk making machine and want to make yoghurt from my home made soy milk.
Yoghurt making sites say that home made milks have to be cooked at almost boiling for 10 minutes before using to make yoghurt, to heat treat the proteins. However, I think these sites generally assume that people are making soy milk without a machine.
That is, just blending soaked beans with water and straining. Made this way, it needs to be cooked before consuming (or turning into yoghurt). But my machine boils and cooks the beans in water and grinds them, and all I have to do is strain the milk. So I am hoping that I can use this as-is to make yoghurt, without needing to cook the milk as an additional step. Does anyone know if this is the case? Guess I can just try it and see!

There are reasons besides heat-treatment of the proteins for heating of the milk - it's to at least partially Pasteurize (heat kill bacteria) it too, so that when you add your starter culture, you are adding it in a vast abundance over any bacteria that might be there already.
In your case it seems to me that the machine does the Pasteurizing step during the cooking of the beans, which will be boiled until soft. The straining step and grinding steps could add bacteria, but if you do these while still hot (>65 C/150 F), it should be fine to then take this into your yogurt without additional heating.
You would need to be sure that the grinding mechanism is cleaned thoroughly and dried each time you use it to ensure that it isn't a site for contamination to get in.
